# Доступ к последнему элементу вектора векторов в c++

Tags: c++, vector, итераторы

Есть вектор векторов `vector<vector<double>> vec`. Он заполняется в методе. Поэтому размерность внутренних векторов бывает разная. Например `{{1,2,3},{4,5}, {5,6,7}}`. Мне нужно получить последний элемент последнего вектора.
Я хотел так:

```
 double a = vec.back().back();
```

Компилятор не ругается, но программа на этой строке вылетает.
Как можно получить этот элемент?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вам еще надо бы учесть, что вектор может быть пустым - тогда программа будет вылетать на такой строке (хоть формально, она и верная).

Можно поступить так:

```
if( !vec.empty() && !vec.back().empty() )
{
    double a = vec.back().back();
}
```

Comment: Это и правда помогло! Спасибо)

Answer (score 1):

В дополнение к ответу gbg: Я бы вынес всё это в функцию и добавил бы исключение при неправильном параметре.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <exception>

using namespace std;

double get_last_of_last(vector<vector<double>>& vec)
{
    if (vec.empty() || vec.back().empty())
    {
        throw runtime_error("unvalid parameter");
    }
    return vec.back().back();
}

int main()
{
    vector<vector<double>> vec = { {1, 2, 3}, {2, 5, 6, 7}, {1, 5, 2, 6, 8} };
    cout << get_last_of_last(vec) << endl;
    system("pause");
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: Нехороший конструктор исключения, принимающий строку. И почему код возврата такой?

Comment: `std::exception` не имеет конструктора от строки, это самодеятельность студии. Нужно `std::runtime_error` или что-то такое.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, исправил. Спасибо за разъяснение. Всё время мне про плохой конструктор говорили, я думал, что нужно какой-то другой конструктор использовать.. Только вот их всего 4 (visual studio 2019), а нужный мне только 1 и он принимает строку. Наконец-то понял.